# play 2.3.6 deadbolt restrict user created resources

Tags: java, playframework-2.3, deadbolt

Is is possible to restrict users to resources only created by them using deadbolt, I know controller methods restrictions and logged in user restriction can be done, but is is possible to let a user CRUD on resources (like photos, documents) created by them, if yes can you guide me to any useful links or examples ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I'm doing it using dynamic routes + @Dynamic. I'll try to give you a short example later, when I get home.

Comment: hey, can you give me an example that you were talking about @sebster

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do the same kind of restrictions, were you able to implement this?

Comment: No, I did it some other way, I wasn't able to use deadbolt for that